# How to remove all values in an ArrayList AFTER a certain value

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, indexing

I'm creating a method that removes all of the index's inside of my ArrayList if it is after the number 10. This is what I have so far:
public class ArrayPost {
public ArrayList myList;

```
public ArrayPost(){
    ArrayList<Integer> List1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myList = List1;
    myList.add(1);
    myList.add(2);
    myList.add(10);
    myList.add(1);
    myList.add(2);
    myList.add(3);
    
}
    
public ArrayList post10(ArrayList list){
    myList = list;
    int i; 
    int x = 10;
     if (x == list.lastIndexOf(x)){
         i = x;
         
        do{
            list.remove(i);  
        }while (i >= 0);
    }        
    
    //System.out.println(myList.toString());
        
return list;  
}
```

}

All this does it print out my ArrayList. It does not remove all of the numbers after 10. If someone could help that would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
 public ArrayList post10(ArrayList list){
        myList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
        for (item : list) clone.add(item.clone());
        myList = list;
        int x = 10;
        for(int i = list.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            if(myList.get(i) == x)
                break;
            myList.remove(i);
            if(i == 0)
                myList = list;

        }
    return myList;  
    }
```

Comment: If the list does not contain 10, then all elements are removed.

Comment: The variables `myList` and `list` refer to the same list object, so the result is unchanged.